# Books for an introduction to professional photography

Tags: selling

I am retired and have invested a good chunk of change on camera equipment & accessories with my wife's permission. I have been doing a few shoots for friends for the practice only, no charge.

In my bag: Canon 7D, 5D MkIII, 24-105mm IS f/4 L, 70-200mm F/4 L, 70-200mm F/2.8 L IS II, 85mm F/1.4, a wide angle lens, Kit lens from my 7D, 5-in-1 reflector kit/stand, a pretty good flash that works.

I would like to start charging for my services in the future. My question for you is, are there any really good books/literature available that will explain the ins & outs for what to charge, what poses work best, what companies to use to order photo albums, prints and things of that sort?

Comment: Howcome you have the F/4 and F/2.8 70-200mm lenses?

Comment: @D3C4FF 785g/27.7oz/1.73lbs/over twice the weight - is the reason to own both. The 70-200mm f/2.8L IS II is a huge heavy piece of glass. The 70-200mm f/4 is not.

Comment: @dpollitt fair enough, i guess if your shooting during the day time  you probably don't need the additional stops anyway

Comment: Frankly, this will be closed as off topic for either not being constructive or not a real question, unless you provide a TYPE of photography that you are looking for books on. With the question as is the options are endless. The other potential problem is that each answer _could_ be considered equally correct. See our FAQ for how to ask questions and what questions to ask - http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: @dpollitt is correct, I think. What "services" are you specifically talking about because the literature, the business requirements, and so on very much differ across the professional market.

Answer (score 1):

You have some impressive equipment but it has nothing to do with the fee you want to charge. The fee should reflect

1. Your photos quality.
2. Your marketing skills.
3. The demand for your services.

From your description it sounds you don't have too much experience, and you didn't mention what are you going to photograph, weddings? sports? journalism?

I suggest you start really cheap, take a symbolic payment and publish your results on the web. Try to get as much as criticism from people you don't know. Then, when you'll get some great responses you can update your rates.

Another place to start testing your skills and make some money is "Stock Photography".
This will improved your technical skills because without them you won't be able to sell your photos or even pass the first selection.

**Edit:** I use and also recommend [Shutterstock](http://submit.shutterstock.com/?ref=168226) . I tried few stock website before and got poor results, not that I'm the best stock photographer :), but shutterstock gives me a nice income and I use it to upgrade my photography gear.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, perhaps barns and nobel will have a book that will further my knowledge along on this matter.

Comment: What stock photography do you use.

Comment: I added the stock website I use to my answer

Comment: The question was about "what books". This answer is in regards to "what fee should I charge" and "how to get started with professional photography". I don't get why this is useful for this question on _BOOKS_.

Comment: The question was edited. Still as far as I know, there are no books that say how much you should charge and my answer is still relevant.

Comment: No books that tell you what to charge? Try any accounting book for small businesses or the hundreds for starting a photography business. Charge what you need to make a profit and continue the business... it isn't special to photography.

Comment: He was retired and it sounds like he is not going to start a new business, so abstract advises like charge what you need to make a profit seems irrelevant to me. Plus - the type of your photo shoot, the economy state, the inflation and much more updated details, were to print your albums and what rates to set cannot be written in a book, they'll become useless very fast, so I still think my advises were relevant to the question.

Comment: Point well taken, and in the meantime I am working on getting started with shutterstock, thank you Itay Gal for your advice. I will make the best of it.